# Formatar data (dd/MM/yyyy)

Tags: winforms, vb.net, data, formatação

Tenho aqui uma coluna numa DataGridview com o nome "DBO" (date of birth) que está com o formato mês/dia/ano, queria mudar o estilo da data para dd-MM-yyyy mas não estou a conseguir.

```
    myCommand = "UPDATE DoctorBasic SET " & _
    "DOB = '" & Convert_Null(DGV1(9, 0).Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), #1/1/1900#)** & "' " & _
    "WHERE DoctorId = " & DGV1(0, 0).Value

    cmd = New SqlCommand(myCommand, myConnectionString)
    MsgBox(myCommand)
    cmd.Connection.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cmd.Connection.Close()
```

O convert_null serve para que apresente esta data 1/1/1900 como pré-definida caso o registo que procure não tenha data e quiser gravar algumas alterações para não dar erro porque o campo está nulo.

Comment: como esta o grid?

Comment: E qual é o problema?

Comment: Me parece que você está tentando atualizar a data no banco a fim de que ela seja mostrada com o formato desejado na tela. Se for este o caso, não é assim que se faz. Você deve formatar a data na hora de exibir - não se preocupe com o formato dela no banco (data no banco de dados não tem formato).

Comment: Sim pelo que percebi é isso que quero.. Quero que se apresente neste formato para poder actualizar a data sem problemas. Como é que posso fazer então?

Answer (score 2):

Faça a alteração no SQL, já que você está usando SQL manual para o *update*:

```
myCommand = "UPDATE DoctorBasic SET " & _
"DOB = convert(datetime, '" & Convert_Null(DGV1(9, 0).Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), #1/1/1900#)** & "', 103) " & _
"WHERE DoctorId = " & DGV1(0, 0).Value
```

[A especificação de `CONVERT()` com o formato 103 pode ser lida aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187928.aspx).

Comment: Obrigada, já alterei a linha mas dá-me este erro: A conversão da cadeia "dd/MM/yyyy" para o tipo 'Integer' não é válida.

Comment: `Integer`? Tem certeza de que suas funções estão trabalhando com o tipo `datetime`?

Comment: não percebi bem a pergunta, quer se referir ao tipo de campo?

Comment: Sim. Aparentemente tem um erro de conversão na hora de montar a string SQL.

Comment: sim isso tenho a certeza. também não percebi o que era o "integer" aqui na string sql

Comment: Acho que já consegui, alterei a linha para isto (...) "DOB = convert(datetime, '" & (DGV1(9, 0).Value.ToString) & "',103), " & _    e penso que agora ja está a funcionar correctamente

Answer (score 0):

```
Algumas dicas :
```

Para jogar data dentro do datagrid, ela pode ficar com texto, você pode percebe quando mandar ordernar, em relação a dia/mês/ano, para ficar como data, fique atento na questão de nulo, que ai deve existir um tratamento, só que muitas vezes deve existir nulo, ai complicar, pois vem mais tratamento, se deixar com texto, é mais fácil o tratamento, pense nisto.

Na questão de formato, você pode utilizar o string.format.